# В чем разница между Vcc, Vdd, Vee и Vss

Tags: arduino, электроника, внешние-устройства

Попадалось множество принципиальных электрических схем, на устройствах, подключаемых к компьютеру, где Vcc и Vdd взаимозаменяемы.

- Знаю, что Vcc и Vdd используются для положительного напряжения, а Vss и Vee для обозначения общей линии (земли), но в чем разница между каждыми из двух вариантов в парах?
- Означают ли знаки C, D, S и E что-либо?

И в дополнение: почему Vdd а не просто Vd ?

Comment: Вопрос хороший, но тут оффтопик :-(

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не соответствует тематике сайта Stack Overflow на русском.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Vcc, Vee, Vdd, Vss** - откуда такие обозначения?

Обозначения цепей питания проистекают из области анализа схем на транзисторах, где, обычно, рассматривается схема с транзистором и резисторами подключенными к нему. Напряжение (относительно земли) на коллекторе (collector), эмиттере (emitter) и базе (base) обозначают **Vc**, **Ve** и **Vb**. Резисторы подключенные к выводам транзистора обозначим **Rc**, **Re** и **Rb**. Напряжение на дальних (от транзистора) выводах резисторов часто обозначают **Vcc**, **Vee** и **Vbb**.

На практике, например для NPN транзистора включенного по схеме с общим эмиттером, **Vcc** соответствуют плюсу, а **Vee** минусу источника питания. Соответственно для PNP транзисторов будет наоборот.
Аналогичные рассуждения для полевых транзисторов N-типа и схемы с общим истоком дают объяснение обозначений **Vdd** и **Vss** (D — drain, сток; S — source, исток): **Vdd** — плюс, **Vss** — минус.

Обозначения напряжений на выводах вакуумных ламп могут быть следующие: Vp (plate, anode), Vk (cathode, именно K, не C), Vg (grid, сетка).

Как написано выше, Vcc и Vee используются для схем на биполярных транзисторах (Vcc - плюс, Vee — минус), а Vdd и Vss для схем на полевых транзисторах (Vdd - плюс, Vss — минус). Такое обозначение не совсем корректно, так как микросхемы состоят из комплементарных пар транзисторов. Например, у КМОП микросхем, плюс подключен к P-FET истокам, а минус к N-FET истокам. Тем не менее, это традиционное устоявшее обозначение для цепей питания независимо от типа проводимости используемых транзисторов.
Для схем с двух полярным питанием Vcc и Vdd могут интерпретироваться как наибольшее положительное, а Vee и Vss как самое отрицательное напряжение в схеме относительно земли.

Для микросхем питающихся от одного или нескольких источников одной полярности минус часто обозначают GND (земля). Земля может быть разной, например, сигнальная, соединение с корпусом, заземление.

Не знаю разрешено ли указывать сторонние ресурсы, но мне кажется будет нечестным умалчивать автора. [РадиоКот](http://radiokot.ru/articles/49/)